# Swift Firebase QueryOrdered

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a registration page for a business location and am comparing if the Latitude and Longitudes match with any existing childs in the database. This code sometimes works and then stops working. When it stops working I would be pressing on the "Create Account Action" and nothing would happen. I added a print("Sign Up Button Tapped Firebase Problem") so I know that the button is actually firing. Why does this code sometimes work and sometimes not? Whats the solution to my problem? Thanks.

```
@IBAction func createAccountAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let email = self.emailTextField.text!
    let password = self.passwordTextField.text!

    if firstName.text == "" {
        CommonUtils.sharedUtils.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: "Please Enter Your First Name.")
    }
    if lastName.text == "" {
        CommonUtils.sharedUtils.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: "Please Enter Your Last Name.")
    }
    if companyPosition.text == "" {
        CommonUtils.sharedUtils.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: "Please Enter Your Company Position.")
    }
    if businessName.text == "" {
        CommonUtils.sharedUtils.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: "Please Enter The Business Name.")
    }
    if businessStreet.text == "" {
        CommonUtils.sharedUtils.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: "Please Enter The Business's Street.")
    }
    if businessCity.text == "" {
        CommonUtils.sharedUtils.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: "Please Enter The City.")
    }
    if businessState.text == "" {
        CommonUtils.sharedUtils.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: "Please Enter The State.")
    }
    if businessZIP.text == "" {
        CommonUtils.sharedUtils.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: "Please Enter The ZIP.")
    }
    if businessPhone.text == "" {
        CommonUtils.sharedUtils.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: "Please Enter The Business's Phone.")
    }
    if businessWebsite.text == "" {
        CommonUtils.sharedUtils.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: "Please Enter The Business Website.")
    }
    if businessLatitude.text == "" {
        CommonUtils.sharedUtils.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: "Please Enter The Business Latitude.")
    }
    if businessLongitude.text == "" {
        CommonUtils.sharedUtils.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: "Please Enter The Business Longitude.")
    }

    print("Sign Up Button Tapped Firebase problem")

    self.ref.child("Businesses").queryOrdered(byChild: "businessLatitude").queryEqual(toValue: self.businessLatitude.text!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if (snapshot.value! is NSNull) {
            print("Not Found - GOOD")
            if email != "" && password != "" && self.firstName.text != "" && self.lastName.text != "" && self.companyPosition.text != "" && self.businessName.text != "" && self.businessStreet.text != "" && self.businessCity.text != "" && self.businessState.text != "" && self.businessZIP.text! != "" && self.businessPhone.text != "" && self.businessWebsite.text != "" && self.businessLatitude.text != "" && self.businessLongitude.text != "" {
                // search for businessLatitude
                CommonUtils.sharedUtils.showProgress(self.view, label: "Registering...")
                FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion:  { (user, error) in
                    if error == nil {
                        FIREmailPasswordAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: email, password: password)
                        self.ref.child("Businesses").child(user!.uid).setValue(["firstName":self.firstName.text!,"lastName":self.lastName.text!, "companyPosition":self.companyPosition.text!,"businessName":self.businessName.text!, "businessStreet":self.businessStreet.text!, "businessCity":self.businessCity.text!, "businessState":self.businessState.text!, "businessZIP":self.businessZIP.text!, "businessPhone":self.businessPhone.text!, "businessWebsite":self.businessWebsite.text!,"businessLatitude":self.businessLatitude.text!, "businessLongitude":self.businessLongitude.text!, "approvalStatus":self.isApproved, "email":email ])
                        CommonUtils.sharedUtils.hideProgress()
                        let photoViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BusinessProfile")
                        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(photoViewController!, animated: true)
                    } else {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
                            CommonUtils.sharedUtils.hideProgress()
                            CommonUtils.sharedUtils.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: (error?.localizedDescription)!)
                        })
                    }
                })
            } else {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Enter email & password!", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                alert.addAction(action)
            }
            } else {
            print(snapshot.value!)
            if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                for snap in snapshots {
                    let thisLongitude = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "businessLongitude").value as! String
                    if thisLongitude == self.businessLongitude.text! {
                        // handle repeated location
                        if snap.exists() == true {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
                                CommonUtils.sharedUtils.hideProgress()
                                CommonUtils.sharedUtils.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: "This Place Already Is Registered")
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**More Info**

If I set this code like this (Code below) and run it, it works yet it does the check if the same "businessLatitude" exists AFTER the user registers and the user is saved into the database. THEN, when I set it back to the code above the above code runs and does the check without registering the user into the database (Exactly what I want). Why does it run after I do the flip-flop? lol

```
if email != "" && password != "" && self.firstName.text != "" && self.lastName.text != "" && self.companyPosition.text != "" && self.businessName.text != "" && self.businessStreet.text != "" && self.businessCity.text != "" && self.businessState.text != "" && self.businessZIP.text! != "" && self.businessPhone.text != "" && self.businessWebsite.text != "" && self.businessLatitude.text != "" && self.businessLongitude.text != "" {
        // search for businessLatitude
        CommonUtils.sharedUtils.showProgress(self.view, label: "Registering...")
        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion:  { (user, error) in
            if error == nil {
                FIREmailPasswordAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: email, password: password)
                self.ref.child("Businesses").child(user!.uid).setValue(["firstName":self.firstName.text!,"lastName":self.lastName.text!, "companyPosition":self.companyPosition.text!,"businessName":self.businessName.text!, "businessStreet":self.businessStreet.text!, "businessCity":self.businessCity.text!, "businessState":self.businessState.text!, "businessZIP":self.businessZIP.text!, "businessPhone":self.businessPhone.text!, "businessWebsite":self.businessWebsite.text!,"businessLatitude":self.businessLatitude.text!, "businessLongitude":self.businessLongitude.text!, "approvalStatus":self.isApproved, "email":email ])
                CommonUtils.sharedUtils.hideProgress()
                let photoViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BusinessProfile")
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(photoViewController!, animated: true)
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
                    CommonUtils.sharedUtils.hideProgress()
                    CommonUtils.sharedUtils.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: (error?.localizedDescription)!)
                })
            }
        })
    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Enter email & password!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
    }

    self.ref.child("Businesses").queryOrdered(byChild: "businessLatitude").queryEqual(toValue: self.businessLatitude.text!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if (snapshot.value! is NSNull) {
            print("Not Found - GOOD")
            } else {
            print(snapshot.value!)
            if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                for snap in snapshots {
                    let thisLongitude = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "businessLongitude").value as! String
                    if thisLongitude == self.businessLongitude.text! {
                        // handle repeated location
                        if snap.exists() == true {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
                                CommonUtils.sharedUtils.hideProgress()
                                CommonUtils.sharedUtils.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: "This Place Already Is Registered")
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**Even More Info**

I just changed my "Read" + "Write" rules in Firebase to "True". I've been reading how this is a security risk? This is working so far, yet I am testing to see if it will stop working like it has before. I will keep this updated....

```
{
"rules": {
".read": "true",
".write": "true",
"Businesses": {
  "$Businesses_id" : {
    ".indexOn": "businessLatitude"
  }
}
}
}
```

**Picture of compiler when setting break point**

[This is the compiler when the code won't work and I set a breakpoint at the top line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61VHq.jpg)

[This is what the compiler looks like after I do the "Hack" to make it work. What is different is "Provider Data/API Key/ User Id"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2rQE.jpg)

Comment: Try to specify the exact part of the code which is getting errors to make this a little more readable.

Comment: You need to do a bit of troubleshooting before posting questions - that way you may find the issue, or at least tell us which line of code isn't working or crashing. Simply add a breakpoint to the self.ref line, run the app, tap the button and then step through it line by line until you find the issue. Also, you may want to rethink all of those if statements as if there are multiple empty fields, its going to show a lot of alerts which is not a good user experience.

Comment: I added more info, If you need more please let me know

Comment: Did I find a bug with firebase or something????

Comment: Anyone have any idea???

Comment: What part of your code *isn't running* (as I mentioned in my above comment). Add a breakpoint, step through the code and when you find what line of code is failing to run, let us know.

Comment: What was "failing" was the whole block of code "self.ref.child("Businesses").queryOrdered" and everything beneath it. The thing is that it wouldn't produce an error, it just wouldn't execute. As I mention in "More Info" how I would do a flip-flop of code to get it to "work". I would set the code to how it is in "More Info", create a user/account, then go to the code and reset it to how it is in the first place(where the check for "businessLongitude" is done before the user is saved) and run the code and then it would magically work, yet stop working unsuspectingly.

Comment: I just added an image of the compiler when I set the break point, maybe you can help point out whats wrong

Comment: I just added a break-point underneath that point to "if (snapshot.value! is NSNull) { ) and it doesn't even fire...

Comment: My best guess is because it's all returning nil

Comment: Can we go to chat?

Comment: Does this still not make sense to you Jay or you just don't know the solution?

Comment: Putting the breakpoint on that line doesn't tell us anything as if that stops the execution before that lines executes. Put the breakpoint on the next line, 126 in the screen shot. In comments, please remember to please put an @ symbol in front of people's names so they will get a inbox message that draws their attention to the comment. I copy and pasted your code into a new project and it works for me.

Comment: @Jay Have you tried both ways the code is? Together and separated? When it is together is works for a little then suddenly won't run. Meaning when I have QueryOrdered as the first line.

Comment: @Jay I am doing like you said and put a breakpoint at "if (snapshot.value! is NSNull)" and it doesn't even execute. Like what I was saying... It wont even fire that point for some reason.

Comment: @Jay for some reason it only works when the user creates a location and it saves into the database and THEN does the check. I have to like hack it for it to do the check before it saves into the database

Comment: @Jay check out the two new photos I added. One is before when the code doesn't even fire. And the second is after I do the "hack" to make it work

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's enough info in the question to actually answer specifically but eliminating some variables may lead to a solution. So let's try to generate an answer by simplifying...

What I did was create a node in Firebase for testing like this:

```
app_name
   Businesses
     bus_0
       businessLatitude: "thing"
     bus_1
       businessLatitude: "test"
     bus_2
       businessLatitude: "stuff"
```

I then created a brand new Firebase project and pasted the following code into the viewDidLoad function. This code is copy and pasted from your question, eliminating most of the 'stuff' in the closure.

//self.ref is a ref to my firebase.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

     self.ref.child("Businesses").queryOrdered(byChild: "businessLatitude")
                                 .queryEqual(toValue: "test")
                                 .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
         if (snapshot.value! is NSNull) {
             print("nothing found")
         } else {
             print("found it!")
             print(snapshot)
         }
     })
}
```

and then built and ran the app. The output was:

```
found it!
Snap (Businesses) {
    "bus_1" =     {
        businessLatitude = test;
    };
}
```

Based on this result, the code in itself works correctly so there must be something else influencing the process. Perhaps another method is getting called or perhaps there's an asynchronous code issue.

I would suggest doing the same thing - create a new project and use the code posted above in it, and see if it works. If so, I would then comment out a lot of the code in your project and try to run it as bare-bones as possible, attempting to reduce the number of variables. Then get it working and add that code back in a bit at a time until it stops working.

Comment: Thank you Ill give it a shot and see what I can come up with

Comment: How can I save current "businessLatitude" and "businessLongitude" in the rules? can my rules have an effect as to why my query doesn't get called?

Comment: @LukasBimba What does 'save' mean? Rules are just that - they provide security to your data and can allow or not allow access to specific nodes of data. They will not have an effect on why your query isn't called - however, they can prevent data from being read/written. Firebase always provides feedback - either as an error condition or a response in the console / Xcode log. For example, if we take your rules and set read to false and attempt a read with the app, *[Firebase/Database][I-RDB038012] Listener at /Businesses failed: permission_denied* is printed to the console.